# SQLCODE=-723 during insertions in DB2

Tags: java, sql, db2

I have a series of insert statements in my code. The table has few triggers to update last updated date and time.

Certain insertions are succeeding while other similar inserts into the table fails with DB2            SQL Error: SQLCODE=-723, SQLSTATE=09000, SQLERRMC=CMSDB.ITNPROD_AUDIT_AFTER_INSERT;-818;51003;, DRIVER=4.8.87

What could be the problem. My worry is it works for certain records whereas fails for other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look up the errors in the DB2 Message reference.

The SQL0723N error ([here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00723n.html)) is telling us that an error occurred in the named trigger (in your case, the trigger is named CMSDB.ITNPROD_AUDIT_AFTER_INSERT).

Furthermore, in the second part of the message, DB2 is telling us that the error that is occurring in the trigger is SQL0818N (SQLSTATE 51003) which is [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00818n.html).

I don't really understand what 818 is saying, but it seems you may have some sort of timestamp problem with a package. Good luck.

Comment: Likely, he's attempting to use a package that was not updated when one of the programs used was updated.  Packages in DB2 are used when connecting to a remote box, and need to be re-created after program re-compile.